# How to run a script under CRON that outputs a CSV file and is then emailed

Tags: php, csv, cron, phpmailer

I need to run a script that queries my DB and outputs the results as a CSV file. I have the script working to produce the CSV I now just need to figure out how to schedule this task for 2am and email the output CSV to a list of email addresses using PHP.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you edit your crontab and simply schedule what you want to happen

e.g.

```
$ crontab -e
```

to edit your crontab. Add an entry to run your script

```
MAILTO=me@example.com
00 02 * * * cd /here && runMy2AMScript
```

And that's about it. your script does all the work, cron just calls it. For more information about crontab - use `man crontab` or `man 5 crontab`.

If your unclear how to schedule sending an email - that's 2 tasks scheduling (which is above) and a script that sends an email - which you can do any number of ways (such as using [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Pick a technique and ask another specific question if you are stuck).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much idea about cron. But once  I tried firing mail using cron. My php site folder is home/USER/www. So this is what I did:

```
1. created a txt file: cron.txt
2. placed cron required informtion : 29 16 * * * php /home/USER/www/test_cron.php
3. ( test_cron.php contains code for a dummy mail )
4. opened terminal and executed command : crontab cron.txt
```

and its been two month and I daily get an email on 4:29pm

Hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

More information would be appreciated. Where do you run into problems? Is it in the scheduling? If so, do a Google search for "Scheduled tasks" in case the webserver is running Windows, or "Cronjobs" if the webserver is running Linux, Unix or BSD.

E-mail a file is rather simple if you use a library; I would suggest looking into [attaching files with Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html).